# Cross validation for glm() models

Tags: r, partitioning, prediction, glm, cross-validation

I'm trying to do a 10-fold cross validation for some glm models that I have built earlier in R. I'm a little confused about the `cv.glm()` function in the `boot` package, although I've read a lot of help files. When I provide the following formula:

```
library(boot)
cv.glm(data, glmfit, K=10)
```

Does the "data" argument here refer to the whole dataset or only to the test set?

The examples I have seen so far provide the "data" argument as the test set but that did not really make sense, such as why do 10-folds on the same test set? They are all going to give exactly the same result (I assume!).

Unfortunately `?cv.glm` explains it in a foggy way:

> data: A matrix or data frame containing the data. The rows should be
>   cases and the columns correspond to variables, one of which is the
>   response

My other question would be about the `$delta[1]` result. Is this the average prediction error over the 10 trials? What if I want to get the error for each fold?

Here's what my script looks like:

```
##data partitioning
sub <- sample(nrow(data), floor(nrow(x) * 0.9))
training <- data[sub, ]
testing <- data[-sub, ]

##model building
model <- glm(formula = groupcol ~ var1 + var2 + var3,
        family = "binomial", data = training)

##cross-validation
cv.glm(testing, model, K=10)
```

Comment: Look at the example section of `boot:::cv.glm`. You should input the whole data, the model and the fold of CV.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RomanLuštrik. Sounds great. I am still wondering about a couple of things though. Does this function use all the supplied data in the cross-validation? suppose I supplied a dataframe of a 1000 rows for the `cv.glm(data, glm, K=10)` does it make 10 paritions of the data, each of a 100 and make the cross validation? Sorry I have been through the ?cv.glm but I did not find that there.

Comment: If you would be doing a 2 fold CV, the function would take 50% of the data and fit the model. It would use the other 50% of the data to see how well the model describes the data. Or, in leave-one-out CV, it would fit the model to all but one data "point", and see how well the singled out "point" did. Repeat N times and you get your result.

Comment: Hi @RomanLuštrik. You said that if I did a 2-fold CV, the function will fit the model according to 50% of the data and use the other 50% as a test set. If the function does that, then why does it require an argument "glmfit" which is a previously fitted model?

Comment: If you have a question on crossvalidation, I suggest you open a thread at crossvalidated.com.

Answer (score 19):

I am always a little cautious about using various packages 10-fold cross validation methods.  I have my own simple script to create the test and training partitions manually for any machine learning package:

```
#Randomly shuffle the data
yourData<-yourData[sample(nrow(yourData)),]

#Create 10 equally size folds
folds <- cut(seq(1,nrow(yourData)),breaks=10,labels=FALSE)

#Perform 10 fold cross validation
for(i in 1:10){
    #Segement your data by fold using the which() function 
    testIndexes <- which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
    testData <- yourData[testIndexes, ]
    trainData <- yourData[-testIndexes, ]
    #Use test and train data partitions however you desire...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake Drew. For testing purpose, I have compared your code above with the results from cv.glm and results are identical. Thanks to your post, I can now trust cv.glm ;-)

Answer (score 6):

@Roman provided some answers in his comments, however, the answer to your questions is provided by inspecting the code with `cv.glm`:

I believe this bit of code splits the data set up randomly into the K-folds, arranging rounding as necessary if K does not divide n:

```
if ((K > n) || (K <= 1)) 
    stop("'K' outside allowable range")
K.o <- K
K <- round(K)
kvals <- unique(round(n/(1L:floor(n/2))))
temp <- abs(kvals - K)
if (!any(temp == 0)) 
    K <- kvals[temp == min(temp)][1L]
if (K != K.o) 
    warning(gettextf("'K' has been set to %f", K), domain = NA)
f <- ceiling(n/K)
s <- sample0(rep(1L:K, f), n)
```

This bit here shows that the delta value is NOT the root mean square error. It is, as the helpfile says `The default is the average squared error function.` What does this mean? We can see this by inspecting the function declaration:

```
function (data, glmfit, cost = function(y, yhat) mean((y - yhat)^2), 
    K = n)
```

which shows that within each fold, we calculate the average of the error squared, where error is in the usual sense between predicted response vs actual response.

`delta[1]` is simply the [weighted average](http://gerardnico.com/wiki/data_mining/cross_validation#cross-validation_error_estimate) of the SUM of all of these terms for each fold, see my inline comments in the code of `cv.glm`:

```
for (i in seq_len(ms)) {
    j.out <- seq_len(n)[(s == i)]
    j.in <- seq_len(n)[(s != i)]
    Call$data <- data[j.in, , drop = FALSE]
    d.glm <- eval.parent(Call)
    p.alpha <- n.s[i]/n #create weighted average for later
    cost.i <- cost(glm.y[j.out], predict(d.glm, data[j.out, 
        , drop = FALSE], type = "response"))
    CV <- CV + p.alpha * cost.i # add weighted average error to running total
    cost.0 <- cost.0 - p.alpha * cost(glm.y, predict(d.glm, 
        data, type = "response"))
}
```